# A bit more advanced TODO list , javascript

Tags: javascript, list, dom

So my HTML page starts [like this](http://postimg.org/image/3nsqpg8b1/full/), and on create **new section** it does [this](http://postimg.org/image/smb3ww4y5/full/) and when i  start to create new **list items** it becomes like [this](http://postimg.org/image/4s1t8jvid/full/), and so far it looks ok..., but when i create my **2nd section** i can't create any new list items in it, or i can but they all print in the 1st section, yes guess probably the id-s are being confused here, but i don't know how to make it work.. .
The same problem i have with the check box before my **list items** text, i just can't make the background color of the my div element turn green when it's checked, due to i guess id confusions in the system.
So my question is how to make it work as intended with multiple **sections** with multiple **list items** in them

So here is my HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="Script1.js" type="text/javascript" ; defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1>Tuesday TODO List</h1>
            <input type="text" id="sectionText" class="sectionText" placeholder="Title" />
            <button id="btn" class="btn">New Section</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here are my styles

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

    div h1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

section {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

input[type=text] {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
}

div.listItem {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
}
h3{
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And most importantly my script

```
var a = document.getElementById('btn');
a.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var section = document.createElement('section');
    section.setAttribute('id', 1);
    document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(section); //apendvame tuka kum bodito
    var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    h3.innerText = document.getElementById('sectionText').value;
    section.appendChild(h3);
    var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text')
    input.setAttribute('id', 'txt');
    section.appendChild(input);
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'txtButton');
    btn.innerText = 'New List Item'
    section.appendChild(btn);

    var b = document.getElementById('txtButton');
    b.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'listItem');
        var checkbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
        checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        checkbox.setAttribute('id', 'checker');
        div.appendChild(checkbox);
        var span = document.createElement('span')
        span.innerText = b.previousElementSibling.value;
        div.appendChild(span);
        document.getElementById('txt').parentNode.insertBefore(div, document.getElementById('txt'));
    }, false);
})
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you assumed correctly, the script "gets confused" by the same ID being used multiple times. An ID is by definition a unique identifier. How should the script know which element you wan to select?

You actually don't even need to select the element by its ID each and every time, as you already have it available in via variabble.

Check this fiddle with some minor modifications:
https://jsfiddle.net/0df3jsad/

P.S: For better performance, you should generally avoid using

```
document.getElementByID()
```

for the same element each and every time you need to do something to it. Just assign it to a variable once and use that reference.

Comment: Hello and thanks! Can you give me a link to more materials or from where you learned that, each and every material i came by, just has so basic explanation dom manipulation, that it makes them useless . And i quote "For better performance, you should generally avoid using", can you give me a link to and article or something explain this to me, cause i was told, that genrally JS works by ID system, and CSS works by  class system

Comment: Well, I can't actually give you specific sources, "where I learned that" is about 18 years of frontend development. ;-) I actually started learning-by-doing and have researched for and read resources whenever I encountered a specific problem.

Regarding the re-use of IDs, that's actually a matter of logic, not JS-specific. Regarding the performance issues, there are countless blogposts and also printed books.

Just use your favourite search engine and try using keywords like "javascript basics", "learn javascript", "javascript performance", etc. There are plenty of resources. Have fun!